# How to find subsets that contains equal sum in an array:

Tags: java, data-structures

How to find subsets that contains equal sum in an array.
For example

```
{1,2,3,4,2}->{1,2,3} && {4,2}
{1,1,3,3,2,8}->{1,3,3,2}&&{1,8}
{1,3,4,7}->no subset
```

I tried with below code, but not getting the appropriate output.

```
import java.util.*

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {1,3,4,7};
    int sum = getSum(arr, arr.length);
    int[] solution = new int[arr.length];
    find(arr, 0, 0, sum, solution);
}    
public static int getSum(int arr[], int n) {
    float sum = 0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    return Math.round(sum / 2);
}
public static void find(int[] A, int currSum, int index, int sum,
        int[] solution) {
    if (currSum == sum) {
        System.out.println("\nSum found");
        for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
            if (solution[i] == 1) {
                System.out.print("  " + A[i]);
            }
        }

    } else if (index == A.length) {
        return;
    } else {
        solution[index] = 1;// select the element
        currSum += A[index];
        find(A, currSum, index + 1, sum, solution);
        currSum -= A[index];
        solution[index] = 0;// do not select the element
        find(A, currSum, index + 1, sum, solution);
    }
    return;
}
```

with this Input Array: 1,2,3,4,2 getting below output

```
1  2  3
1  3  2
2  4
4  2
```

Input Array: 1,1,3,3,2,8

```
1  3  3  2
1  8
1  3  3  2
1  8
```

Input Array:1,3,4,7

```
1  3  4
1  7
```

Comment: Your code has compile error. `getSum` method is void but you are setting to int. Please fix.

Comment: This is a classic problem, although not so easy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: I have updated the getSum method.

Comment: your code is calculating all possible results. What's the problem then?

Comment: Do not learn languages and libraries until you have a fair understanding of programming techniques. Find the sum of every possible combination and store it (together with the combination) in a sorted map (RB-tree or whatever). Then find the sums that are equal.

Comment: This is a variation to subset sum problem (NP-Hard). It is possible to be solved in Pseudo-polynomial time with dynamic programming

Comment: @Kaidul Program should not repeat the output.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem you need to have at least 3 nested loop in your code
the sudocode will be like

```
for (i=0,i< array.length-1,i++){
 for(k=i;k<array.length-1,k++){ 
  fsum=findSum(i/*from*/,k/*to*/,array);
  ssum=0;

  for(x=k,x<array.length,x++){
    secondsum=findSum(k,x,array);
    if(fsum==ssum){
     prend(i,k,array);
     print(k,x,array);
     break;
    }

   }




 }



}
```

note that this is just sudo code need to implement

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence part of your code works fine. There are only two minor flaws in rather peripheral parts:

1. The two subsets only exists if the sum of the numbers is even. Your code doesn't consider this requirement which is the reason for the failure concerning {1,3,4,7}. For this, the body of the main function is slightly modified so that the recurrence is performed only for even sums.
2. You should sort out the duplicates which would prevent the repetitions concerning {1,2,3,4,2} and {1,1,3,3,2,8}. For this, the resulting subsets quite simply have to be stored. Then, after the elemination of the duplicates the remaining subsets are printed out. For convenience both functionalities are encapsulated in the added SubsetPair-class which provides the methods storeSubsetPair and printSubsetPairList for storage and printing, respectively.

The modified code is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {1,3,4,7};
        int sum = getSum(arr, arr.length);
        int[] solution = new int[arr.length];
        // find(arr, 0, 0, sum, solution); // REPLACED WITH: -----------------
        if (sum % 2 == 0) { 
            sum = Math.round(sum / 2f);
            find(arr, 0, 0,sum, solution);
        }
        SubsetPair.printSubsetPairList(); 
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    }    
    public static int getSum(int arr[], int n) {
        // float sum = 0f; // REPLACED WITH: ---------------------------------
        int sum = 0;
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sum = sum + arr[i];
        // return Math.round(sum / 2); // REPLACED WITH: ---------------------
        return sum;
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
    public static void find(int[] A, int currSum, int index, int sum,
            int[] solution) {
        if (currSum == sum) {
            // System.out.println("\nSum found"); // REPLACED WITH: ----------
            // for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
            //    if (solution[i] == 1) {
            //        System.out.print("  " + A[i]);
            //    }
            // }
            SubsetPair.storeSubsetPair(A, solution);
            // ---------------------------------------------------------------
        } else if (index == A.length) {
            return;
        } else {
            solution[index] = 1;// select the element
            currSum += A[index];
            find(A, currSum, index + 1, sum, solution);
            currSum -= A[index];
            solution[index] = 0;// do not select the element
            find(A, currSum, index + 1, sum, solution);
        }
        return;
    }
}

//NEW: Class for storage and print:
class SubsetPair {

    private static List<SubsetPair> subsetPairList = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<Integer> subset1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer> subset2 = new ArrayList<>();

    //
    // Storage of the subset pair
    //
    public static void storeSubsetPair(int[] A,  int[] solution) {
        SubsetPair subsetPair = new SubsetPair();
        for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
            if (solution[i] == 1) {
                subsetPair.subset1.add(A[i]);
            } else {
                subsetPair.subset2.add(A[i]); 
            }
        } 
        if (!subsetPair.isDuplicate()) {
            subsetPairList.add(subsetPair);
        }
    }   

    // Remove duplicates
    private boolean isDuplicate() {
        for (SubsetPair subsetPair : subsetPairList) {
            if (isEqual(subset1, subsetPair.subset2) && isEqual(subset2, subsetPair.subset1) || 
                isEqual(subset1, subsetPair.subset1) && isEqual(subset2, subsetPair.subset2)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isEqual(List<Integer> subset1, List<Integer> subset2) {
        return subset1.containsAll(subset2) && subset2.containsAll(subset1);
    }

    //
    // Output of the subset pairs
    //
    public static void printSubsetPairList() {
        if (subsetPairList.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No subset-pairs found!");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < subsetPairList.size(); i++) {
                subsetPairList.get(i).printSubsetPair(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void printSubsetPair(int i) {
        System.out.print(i + ". Subset-Pair:\n");
        System.out.print("Subset 1: ");
        for (Integer i1 : subset1) {
            System.out.print(i1 + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Subset 2: ");
        for (Integer i2 : subset2) {
            System.out.print(i2 + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n\n");
    }
}
```

With those changes the output becomes:

For {1,2,3,4,2} with an even sum of 12:

```
  1. Subset-Pair:
  Subset 1: 1 2 3 
  Subset 2: 4 2
```

For {1,1,3,3,2,8} with an even sum of 18:

```
  1. Subset-Pair:
  Subset 1: 1 3 3 2 
  Subset 2: 1 8
```

For {1,3,4,7} with an odd sum of 15:

```
  No subset-pairs found!
```

For {3,1,1,2,2,1} with an even sum of 10:

```
  1. Subset-Pair:
  Subset 1: 3 1 1 
  Subset 2: 2 2 1 

  2. Subset-Pair:
  Subset 1: 3 2 
  Subset 2: 1 1 2 1
```

For {2,4,8} with an even sum of 14:

```
  No subset-pairs found!
```

As in the comments already stated the problem is related to the "partition problem" which is the task to decide if a multiset of positive integers can be partitioned into two subsets with equal sum. This is in detail explained e.g. in 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem or in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-problem-dp-18/ (the latter includes a Java implementation). But both problems are **not exactly identical** because the solution of the "partition problem" just answers the question **if** the multiset can be partitioned into two subsets, but does not **explicitly** determine the subsets itself.